# how to execute python script containing django functions

Tags: python, django

I have a python script `test.py` that imports `make_password` function from Django library. It does it like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

.... a lot of other stuff
def init():
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
```

So, I want to run it from the command line like:

```
python test.py
```

But this results in a whole list of error messages, which are all about importing Django module. If I comment out `from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password`, then everything is ok (except the fact that I can't use `make_password` function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages your are getting are most likely complaints that the settings module is not available.

Django initializes its runtime environment (via `django.core.management.setup_environ()`) when you import any of its core modules. The django ecosystem is not meant to function without a valid project environment.

You have at least two options:

**1. Manually set django settings module**

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'yourapp.settings'

from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
...
```

Note that this requires `yourapp.settings` to be available via `sys.path`, so it might be necessary to explicitly add the project path to `sys.path` (or `PYTHON_PATH`).

Other versions of basically the same thing [are available](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/).

**2. Build a management command**

This is explained in some detail in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/).

In principle, you need to provide a `yourapp.management.mycommand` module that contains a single `Command` class:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
       # make_password()
```

The command can be run through django's `manage.py`.

Comment: One tiny question is how to set `yourapp.settings`. I have a project proj1 and I have an application called accent (they are in the same folder). So, how should I specify `yourapp.settings`? Should it be `proj1.settings` or `accent.settings` or should I use the full path to the application (or the project?)

Comment: Well, in both cases - I tried `proj1.settings` and `accent.settings` - I get an error `No module name proj1.settings` or `No module named accent.settings`, respectively. So, there should be some magic with how to set `'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'`

Comment: You use the project's settings module, i.e. `proj1.settings`. Also, the project module needs to be available via Python's module path. You might need to add the project's root directory to `sys.path` (or `PYTHON_PATH`) if the script is not at the root of the project directory.